# Separate proxy settings for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

Google Chrome, by default uses the system's proxy settings, as depicted in this screenshots from the settings screen of Google Chrome.

[image]

Is it in anyway possible to have Google Chrome take on manual settings and not from default system settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change it, by editing the Target in the Chrome-properties.

> 1. Go to the shortcut you use to open Google Chrome.
> 2. Right-click the shortcut and select `Properties`.
> 3. To use a different proxy server, go to the `Target` text box. Go to the end of the text, add a space and input the following:
>
>    > ```
>    > --proxy-server="ipaddress:port"
>    > ```
>
>    Where ipaddress is the address of the desired proxy server and port
>      is the desired port. For example
>
>    > –proxy-server=”192.168.1.5:8080″    Make sure to include the quotes.
>
>    To disable the proxy settings, go to the Target textbook. Go to the
>      end of the text, add a space and input the following:
>
>    > ```
>    > --no-proxy-server="
>    > ```
> 4. Click OK.

[Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5245/google-chrome-how-to-assign-a-proxy-server-that-is-different-from-internet-explorers-settings/)

Comment: This did not work for me